# How to store data in sql database in php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have created register form using php and jquery. I need to store input details to sql database.

I created config.php and included in index.php and submit.php file.

But still didn't store in database, may i know what is my mistake in config.php code, can anyone please help me?

This is my config.php code:

```
    <?php
// configuration
$username       = "root";
$password       = "";

// database connection

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crop', $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO crop VALUES (:one, :two, :three)");

// values to enter
$data = array(
    'one' => 'value one',
    'two' => 'value two',
    'three' => 'value tree'
);

if ($stmt->execute($data)) echo "Inserted successfully";
?>
```

Comment: `But still didn't store in database,`..Where is your insert query?

Comment: You are not using `$dbtype`. Do you want to use SQLite or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the way to do it. You have to use an INSERT statement, not SELECT.

Try the following example:

You have to change the code based on your database structure. In here i just assume there's a table called table and there are 3 fields.

```
<?php

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (:one, :two, :three)");

// values to enter
$data = array(
    'one' => 'value one',
    'two' => 'value two',
    'three' => 'value tree'
);

if ($stmt->execute($data)) echo "Inserted successfully";
```

Comment: what is that :one, :two, :three ?

Comment: :one, :two, and :tree are just alias (array index). see the array, the value of one is 'value one'. so :one is (=) 'value one'. likewise :two is 'value two'. when its executed the value of :one, :two, and :tree will be inserted. those values are value one, value two and value tree

Comment: can you show, the exact config.php code to connect database? I am new to php.

Comment: your config file should work. if you are new i suggest reading a little bit more than directly jumping to code.

Answer (score -1):

That's not the way to get it done.

`$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$table." ('column1', 'column2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2');");
$stmt->execute();`

But I suggest you bind the query first to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: can you show, the exact config.php code to connect database?

Comment: `// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
 $DB_NAME = 'database';
 $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DB_USER = 'root';
 $DB_PASS = 'password';
 
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', ''.$DB_USER.'', ''.$DB_PASS.'');` But I really recommend you search on Google about SQL injection. You have to bind the query like Haris showed to avoid people hacking into your database.

Comment: I want to know, how to insert the data to database?

Comment: There's a whole tutorial here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: please just see my updated post, may i know what can i include in these lines, $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO crop VALUES(:name)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':name' => 'Justin Bieber'
  ));

Comment: are you there? @just some guy