# How to store user input details in back end using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created register form using PHP and jQuery. I need to store input details to SQL database.

I created config.php and included in index.php and submit.php file.

Here is my config.php file:

```
<?php
// configuration
$username       = "root";
$password       = "";

// database connection

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crop', $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO crop VALUES (:one, :two, :three)");

// values to enter
$data = array(
    'one' => 'value one',
    'two' => 'value two',
    'three' => 'value tree'
);

if ($stmt->execute($data)) echo "Inserted successfully";
?>
```

I have  included config.php file in index.php and submit.php.

Now all the fields filled. it shows registered successful, but it didn't store in database.

Comment: Check your DB name and table name are all crop?

Comment: yes, crop only.. and in header of index.php and submit.php i wrote like this, require "config.php";

Comment: I have tried, mine is ok, i am on holding to your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of your previous question: [How to store data in sql database in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210259/how-to-store-data-in-sql-database-in-php). Please don't ask questions more than once here.

Answer (score -1):

Change you array to:

```
$data = array(
    ':one' => 'value one',
    ':two' => 'value two',
    ':three' => 'value tree'
);
```

Comment: Have you tried with specifying the row names? "INSERT INTO crop (name1, name2, name3) VALUES ( :one, :two, :three )"

Comment: yeah, I have tried in my table, and add `:` or not does not matter, I think something else error in his code